# ScalaTest plugin in eclipse not finding my class

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, junit4, scalatest

I'm trying to use ScalaTest to test a Java project. I've written the test and it works (I know that because I've successfully ran them in IntelliJ), but I've yet to make it work in eclipse.

Here is my code (The inside of the test shouldn't be too important):

```
@ContextConfiguration(
  classes = Array(classOf[OrderApplicationSpecContext]),
  loader = classOf[SpringApplicationContextLoader])
class PlacingOrderSpec extends path.FunSpec with org.scalatest.Matchers {

  @Autowired val orderApplication: OrderApplication = null
  @Autowired val customerRepository: CustomerRepository = null
  @Autowired val orderRepository: OrderRepository = null
  @Autowired val creditCardService: CreditCardService = null

  new TestContextManager(this.getClass).prepareTestInstance(this)

  describe("Placing an Order") {

    describe("With an existing customer") {

      val customer = new Customer()
      customerRepository.save(customer)

      it("should return a valid order ID") {
        val orderId = orderApplication.placeOrder(123L, customer.getTid, "123")
        orderId should not be null
      }

      describe("When the credit card is not maxed out and not expired") {

        Mockito.when(creditCardService.isMaxedOut("123", 1.23)).thenReturn(false)
        Mockito.when(creditCardService.expirationDate("123")).thenReturn(LocalDate.MAX)

        it("Should create an order with status <IN PROGRESS>") {
          val orderId = orderApplication.placeOrder(123L, customer.getTid, "123")
          val orderStatus = orderApplication.getOrderStatus(orderId)

          orderStatus should be("IN PROGRESS")
        }

        it("Should create an order accessible from the customer") {
          val orderId = orderApplication.placeOrder(123L, customer.getTid, "123")
          val orders = orderApplication.findOrdersForCustomer(customer.getTid)

          orders should not be empty
          Inspectors.forExactly(1, orders) {
            _.getTid should be (orderId)
          }
        }

      }

      describe("When the credit card is maxed out") {

        Mockito.when(creditCardService.isMaxedOut("123", 1.23)).thenReturn(true)

        it("Should create an order with status <PAYMENT FAILED>") {
          val orderId = orderApplication.placeOrder(123L, customer.getTid, "123")
          val orderStatus = orderApplication.getOrderStatus(orderId)

          orderStatus should be("PAYMENT FAILED")
        }

        it("Should create an order not accessible from the customer") {
          val orderId = orderApplication.placeOrder(123L, customer.getTid, "123")
          val orders = orderApplication.findOrdersForCustomer(customer.getTid)

          Inspectors.forAll(orders) {
            _.getTid should not be(orderId)
          }
        }

      }

      describe("When the credit card is expired") {
        Mockito.when(creditCardService.isMaxedOut("123", 1.23)).thenReturn(false)
        Mockito.when(creditCardService.expirationDate("123")).thenReturn(LocalDate.now().plusMonths(1))

        it("Should create an order with status <PAYMENT FAILED>") {
          val orderId = orderApplication.placeOrder(123L, customer.getTid, "123")
          val orderStatus = orderApplication.getOrderStatus(orderId)

          orderStatus should be("PAYMENT FAILED")
        }

        it("Should create an order not accessible from the customer") {
          val orderId = orderApplication.placeOrder(123L, customer.getTid, "123")
          val orders = orderApplication.findOrdersForCustomer(customer.getTid)

          Inspectors.forAll(orders) {
            _.getTid should not be(orderId)
          }
        }
      }

      customerRepository.deleteAll()

    }

  }

}
```

What I've tried :

- Menu `Run > Run As...` : There are no options applicable.
- Create a new "ScalaTest" configuration. But when I want to select my "Suite Class", no class is found.
- put the @RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner]) on top of my class. Then I can do `Menu Run > Run As... > Junit Test`. But I get an error saying "No JUnit Test found".

However, I can right click on my project, create a Scala interpreter and type `(new PlacingOrderSpec()).execute()`, which will work (but won't use the IDE's junit view and forces me to recompile manually after each change.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally succeeded to run my tests with JUnit.

The problem was the missing `package` statement at the top of my file. With that and the `@RunWith` annotation, I'm able to run the tests with JUnit. It still doesn't work with the ScalaTest plugin, however, but that's fine for my case.

Other answers welcome for the ScalaTest plugin issue.